# Create a Custom URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, .htaccess

Is there a way one can create custom permalinks in Wordpress?

For instance I am trying to create the following url:

website.com/our-services/douchebag-removal

but when I create the page douchebag removal I can not add the / to the permalink so it can look like this our-services/douchebag-removal.

This is what I get:

website.com/our-servicesdouchebag-removal

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: Hello!, but our-services is your category and douchebag-removal is the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple one that gets me every time, on the our-douchebag-removal page you need to chose the parent page "Our Services" in order for the url path to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! yep that was it!

Comment: You're very welcome! I just revisted this one tonight on a site I'm working on, so it's fresh in my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, easier to use and not needing you to create parent pages: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ It's basically a plugin that allows you to put any url on a wordpress page/post. Let me know if it helped!